# How to find mobile phone vendor using j2me?

Tags: java-me, mobile-application

How to get device vendor using j2me.Im developing a mobile application using J2ME.That application perform some process with respect to mobile phone vendor such as nokia,samsung,etc.If the mobile phone is nokia then it done some operation,if it is samsung then it is perfomr some operation.

Here my requirement is i need to find the mobile phone vendor and perform the according process at run tim (That is the application cannot know which vendor it is at compile time.Only at runtime only the application find the mobile phone vendor and perform the process ).But i does not know how to find mobile phone vendor whether it is nokia or samsung or else other using J2ME.

Answer (score 2):

see method getCellId here

http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589